# editable ComboBox: issues with getValue()

Tags: types, combobox, casting, javafx

I'm having issues wrapping my head around what `getValue()` actually returns, or rather: Eclipse seems to have that issue. This is my ComboBox:

```
ComboBox<Integer> intBox = new ComboBox<Integer>;
ObservableList<Integer> intList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

I fill the `ComboBox` with Integers from `intList` by doing:

```
intBox.getItems().addAll(intList);
```

And I also set the `ComboBox` to editable by doing `setEditable(true)`.

The problem is that if I try to store the value of `intBox.getValue()` in an `Integer` or `int` variable, I get "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer" during runtime". But if I try to store it into a `String` instead, Eclipse gives me the compile error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer 
     to String". So the compiler tells me its an Integer, but I still can't store it in an Integer, why?

I've also tried various workarounds, like `Integer.parseInt`, `getValue().intValue()` and `Integer.toString()`, and storing those values in various variables of different datatypes, but they've all given me the same or similar errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html):

> Because a ComboBox can be editable, and the default means of allowing
>   user input is via a TextField, a string converter property is provided
>   to allow for developers to specify how to translate a users string
>   into an object of type T, such that the value property may contain it.
>   By default the converter simply returns the String input as the user
>   typed it, which therefore assumes that the type of the editable
>   ComboBox is String. If a different type is specified and the ComboBox
>   is to be editable, it is necessary to specify a custom
>   StringConverter.

Basically, if the `ComboBox` is editable, it will get its value from the editor (a `TextField`), which supplies a `String`. If you have an editable combo box whose type is not `String`, you need to supply a way to convert the string from the text field to the value of the appropriate type, and vice-versa. So you need

```
intBox.setConverter(new IntegerStringConverter());
```